# $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Until this morning I was pretty sure that the answer was yes. It should have the same cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}$, which is countable. Besides the cartesian product of countable set should be countable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set).

Yet this morning a professor of mine told me that it is not and gave me this proof:

It is clear that $\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\} \subset \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. Now, an element of $\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$ can be seen as a succession $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $x_n$ can be $0$ or $1$.
I.e. if we consider $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ the binary representation of the decimal part of a real number, then $\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$ should be the set of all real numbers between $0$ and $1$, i.e. $[0,1]$, which is uncountable. So also $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

I feel a bit confused as I don't see any error in my professor's proof, yet I don't see how can this be coherent with the countability of the cartesian product of countable sets.

Comment: Your professor confused $\mathbb N \times \{0,1\}$ and $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An element of $\Bbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$ is a tuple $(n, \varepsilon)$ with $\varepsilon \in \{0,1\}$.

A succsession $(x_n)_n$ (also called sequence) is an element of $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb{N}}$, the set of all maps $\Bbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$.

So the argument shows that $\{0,1\}^\Bbb{N}$ is uncountable, and so is

$$
\Bbb{N}^\Bbb{N} \supset \{0,1\}^\Bbb{N},
$$

the set of all maps $\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$.

But this does **not** imply that the set $\Bbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$ is uncountable. You can also write

$$
\Bbb{N} \times \{0,1\} = \bigcup_n \{(n,0), (n,1)\},
$$

so that it is clear that $\Bbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$ is countable as a countable union of finite (hence countable) sets.

So either your professor or you were confused, or you did not completely understand what your professor wanted to say.

All in all: $\Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N}$ **is** countable.

Comment: I definitely believe it was me who was confused (though maybe my prof was a bit responsible for it). Thanks for clarifying! :)

Comment: Couldn't we also just construct a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ to show it is countable?

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan: Yes of course. But my answer was intended to clarify why the argument given by the OP to "show" that $\Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N}$ is **un**countable is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\phi:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ by $\phi(n,m)=2^n3^m.$ you can convince yourself that $\phi$ is injective. so $\phi$ restrcited to its range is bijective. Thus card$(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})=$card$(\mathbb{N})$

Comment: While correct, it doesn't *really* answer the question: what is wrong with the proof that was given by the professor (the answer, as PhoemueX points out, is that the professor answered the question for $\{0,1\}^\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb{N^N}$, rather than $\Bbb{N\times N}$ and $\Bbb N\times\{0,1\}$).

Comment: nothing wrong with that proof. just wanted to present my proof plus answered the question perfectly.

Comment: "I feel a bit confused as I don't see any error in my professor's proof, yet I don't see how can this be coherent with the countability of the cartesian product of countable sets." (Quoted from the question) I don't know where your answer addresses this issue. But since you claim that you have answered the question *perfectly*, I'm sure that you have, and that it's hidden between the letters. Perhaps in a tiny tiny font that I couldn't see on my monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious mistake in interpretation of multiplication and exponentiation, as pointed out by PhoemueX, here is some other points to note:

1. If we consider a binary sequence as a *decimal* representation, we will definitely not get the entire interval $[0,1]$. For example $0.5$ will never ever ever be equal to a number whose decimal expansion consists only of the digits $0,1$. (At least not if set theory is consistent...)
2. If we consider the binary sequence as a *binary* representation of a real number in $[0,1]$ then we get some numbers twice, for example $0.0\overline 1$ and $0.1\overline 0$ are both exactly $\frac12$ (remember that these numbers are binary, not decimal!).

   So while we get that the result is the entire interval, it's not a bijection, so we don't quite have that $\Bbb N\times\{0,1\}$ or even $\{0,1\}^\Bbb N$ is "the set of all numbers in $[0,1]$", since this seems to imply that each number has a unique representation as a binary string.

In any case, the crux of the mistake is the confusion (perhaps due to a communication error when asking the question) between the Cartesian product and set exponentiation.

Comment: Maybe my question was not completely clear but with "binary representation of the decimal part" I meant the binary representation of the fractional part of real numbers between 0 and 1. We need to specify that it is the fractional part otherwise we are considering infinitely large numbers. Anyway, the problem of non-unique representation of some numbers should be negligible if we are wondering about countability, as the numbers with double representation are actually countable...right?
btw, yes, the mistake in the original question is definitely my fault :)

Comment: First of all, every number in $[0,1)$ is the fractional part of itself, since the integral part is $0$. Secondly, negligible doesn't mean that you can immediately ignore it, you still need to acknowledge that it's there. Even more, since you are asking this sort of question, the initial assumption is that you would know very little about set theory, and in particular the fact that we can ignore a countable part of a set of size continuum. I can't tell from reading your question whether you know that stuff or not. I left my mind reading cap in the office, so I can only get it next week. Sorry!